# Terminal not allowing single quotes

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, terminal.app

For some reason when I paste text into terminal it strips out single quotes. I also can't type single quotes. Double quotes seem to work fine. I don't have any problems with other programs AND when I work remotely on an SSH connection I can write/paste single quotes. I also get an 'error' noise when I try to type of paste a single quote.

Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: What shell are you using? Have you changed its configuration recently? Or has it always been like that?

Comment: I just noticed it a few days ago while trying to work out an awk command. However, I don't type single quotes very often. I'm using bash.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you pasting into? xterm? Gnome terminal? Also, what happens when you type two single quotes in a row?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug in homebrew's bash recipe as I managed to fix this by uninstalling [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)'s bash.

Time for a drink perhaps?!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Windows 10 using Git Bash, I could type single quotes in vim and in SSH sessions, but not in the Bash terminal. Turns out that the problem was that I had a `~/.inputrc` file which contained this:

```
'set completion-ignore-case On'
```

The single quotes in that line are breaking something in the input handling, removing them (or deleting the file) and restarting Bash fixes it.